# MySQL dynamic columns - column_create does not exist

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, dynamic-tables

MariaDB 5.3 introduced dynamic columns. From my understanding the next version of mysql should have similar features mariadb has?

I am currently running mysql 5.5.9 and I wanted to mess around with dynamic columns per row.

So I read up on the mysql website, in order to get this working:

innodb_file_format should be set to Barracuda.

Done.

```
--------------
show variables like "%innodb_file%"
--------------

+--------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name            | Value     |
+--------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_file_format       | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_format_check | ON        |
| innodb_file_format_max   | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_per_table    | ON        |
+--------------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then go ahead and create my table for testing

```
 CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dyn` blob,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

I then try to insert

```
 insert into test(`dyn`) VALUES (COLUMN_CREATE(1, "black", 3, "Linux"))
```

I get the following error:

```
 FUNCTION db.COLUMN_CREATE does not exist
```

So my question is does mysql not offer these functions? Should I switch to mariadb for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html), it seems that MySQL does *not* offer this feature.

The dynamic row format actually offers a different method for storing rows that may be more efficient in some cases, **not** a way to have a variable table schema:

> When innodb_file_format is set to Barracuda and a table is created
>   with ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, long column values
>   are stored fully off-page, and the clustered index record contains
>   only a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page.

---

If you need such a flexible schema, check out the [entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern.